# dealing with catastrophic exceptions

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions

I read in a C# introductory book that you shouldn't catch an exception if you don't know what to do with it.  Thinking of that bit of advice while programming in Java, I sometimes find I do not know what to do with an exception, but I am forced to catch it or "percolate it up" to avoid a compile error.  I'd rather not clutter methods with `throws` clauses all the way up the call tree so I have often resorted to "converting" the exception to a `RuntimeException` as in the following.  Adding `throws` clauses to many methods for an exception that isn't really "handled" (properly dealt with) seems verbose and distracting.  Is the following bad style and if so what is a better way to deal with this?

```
try {
  thread.join();
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Console.printwriter.format("%s\n", e.printStackTrace());
  throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Edit: Aside from the clutter, there's another problem with the percolating exceptions: after code revisions you probably end up with some unnecessary `throws` clauses.  The only way I know to clean them out is by trial and error: remove them and see if the compiler complains.   Obviously, this is annoying if you like to keep the code clean.

Comment: The better way to deal with it is to write code in a way where you don't have to throw exceptions constantly.

Comment: Agreed. I generally don't declare many newly defined exceptions. I'm mainly concerned about third-party and Java exceptions.

Comment: @user1394965 Yes, your code should not throw exceptions "constantly". But that is a very different matter to whether exceptions are possible. Anything involving IO operations or blocking methods is likely to be riddled with unavoidable exception handling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrapping a checked exception into an unchecked exception in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484794/wrapping-a-checked-exception-into-an-unchecked-exception-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The division in Java between checked and unchecked exceptions is [somewhat controversial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions?rq=1).

If you control the interface, adding a throws clause to the signature is usually the best way.

If you are in a situation where you cannot deal with an exception, but are not allowed to let it bubble up because of the checked exception signature, then wrapping the exception into an exception that you can rethrow (often a RuntimeException) is common practice.

In many cases, you'd want to use another checked exception, though, such as IOException or SQLException. But that is not always an option.

But in your example, include the original exception as the "cause":

```
 throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

This may also remove the need for the logging (because this can also be deferred to someone who can handle the exception, and all information is still there).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what to do with the exception, you should not catch it. Therefore, your method will now throw an exception, so it should have a throws clause if it is not a runtime exception. There is nothing wrong with them.

Comment: @broiyan Yes, I was answering in the context of your question, where you are dealing with a normal exception.

Answer (score 1):

I like the advice in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java 2nd edition - *Throw exceptions appropriate to the abstraction* (Item 61).

That is, when faced with a series of exceptions you wish to "percolate" out of your method, consider whether the exceptions should be re-wrapped with something that makes more semantic sense for your method.

Such an approach often has the pleasing side effect of combining several lower-level exceptions into a single higher-level exception.

Comment: It's a balancing act between the benefit of simplifying the exceptions thrown versus inventing hundreds of custom exceptions that bloat your code base.

Answer (score 1):

Good programming practices tell that you should hide the internal state of your objects from invokers and, at least for me, that also includes Exceptions. You should see what is the meaning of that exception for you and return to the invokers of your class an Exception representing that meaning.

If the framework already offers an exception with that meaning, for example IllegalArgumentException, you should instanciate a new object, give it a string with a good description of what happened and encapsulate the ocurred exception, something along the lines of new IllegalArgumentException("The argument X is invalid because of ...", e);
If the framework doesn't has a good descriptive exception for your problem, you should create your own set of exceptions. I normally create a generic exception for that project/package (that will extend Exception or RuntimeException) and derivate exceptions from that.
For example, I recently created a generic repository project to be reused across our services and aplication modules to access the database. Since I wanted to abstract invokers from what I was using to access the DB, even from exceptions, I ended up creating some exceptions to encapsulate JPA Hibernate exceptions. I don't have the code here, but it was something similar to:

```
// implementation package
public abstract class GenericRepository<K, E extends<K>> implements IRepository<K, E>{

    //  constructors

    public final void add(E entity){
        // some code

        try{
            //  code that can throw exceptions
        } catch (EntityExistsException e) {
            //  some code
            throw new EntityAlreadyExistsException(e);
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            //  some code
            throw new GenericRepositoryException("An unexpected exception occurred while manipulating the database", e);
        }
    }

    //  some other code

}


// exception package
public final class EntityAlreadyExistsException extends GenericRepositoryException{

    public static final String GENERICMESSAGE = "The entity already exists on the table";

    public EntityAlreadyExistsException(Throwable cause){
        super(GENERICMESSAGE, cause);
    }

    //  other constructors

}
```