# CompletableFutures and exception handling in Java

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

I'm new to the whole CompletableFutures business. Currently, I'm trying to populate a futures list with objects retrieved from a service call and then return the list itself. However, I'm getting 
`error: unreported exception InvalidRequestException; must be caught or declared to be thrown` and `unreported exception DependencyFailureException; must be caught or declared to be thrown` errors even though I'm using a try/catch block and declare the exceptions.
Here's what I have so far:

```
public List<Dog> getDogs(List<String> tagIds, String ownerId) 
        throws InvalidRequestException, DependencyFailureException {

    List<CompletableFuture<Dog>> futures = new ArrayList<>(tagIds.size());
    List<Dog> responses = new ArrayList<>(tagIds.size());

    for(String tagId : tagIds) {
        futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return getDog(tagId, ownerId);
            } catch (InvalidRequestException ire) {
                throw new InvalidRequestException("An invalid request to getDog", ire);
            } catch (DependencyFailureException dfe) {
                throw new DependencyFailureException("A dependency failure occurred during a getDog call", dfe);
            }
        }));
    }
    return futures.stream()
          .map(CompletableFuture::join)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Presumably your `InvalidRequestException` and `DependencyFailureException` types are checked. The `Supplier` functional interface does not declare throwing any checked exceptions, let alone your custom ones. You'll need to handle them internally or rethrow them wrapped in an unchecked exception type.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis, do you have an example of how to go about doing something like that?

Comment: An example of what? Handling is up to you, whatever process you've setup in your application. Wrapping in an uncheckedexception is also discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484794/wrapping-a-checked-exception-into-an-unchecked-exception-in-java).